# iOS Simulator doesn't launch with Calabash

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

I have Calabash installed as a pod in my project. The gem itself is installed using bundler. When I try to run cucumber for my Calabash target, the first features starts but just hangs and the simulator never launches:

```
$ bundle exec cucumber
Feature: Ensure Login and Oauth Screen Functionality

  Scenario: Verify Welcome Page                 # features/Sign_in.feature:3
```

More details from my install:

```
# xcode installation location
$ xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

# xcode version
$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 5.1.1
Build version 5B1008

# calabash version
$ bundle exec calabash-ios version
0.9.168

# calabash < 0.9.169 or Xamarin IDE users
# start your app manually in the simulator or from Xcode and then launch a console
$ bundle exec calabash-ios console
> server_version
{
                        "outcome" => "SUCCESS",
                         "app_id" => "[REDACTED]",
               "simulator_device" => "iPhone",
                        "version" => "0.9.168",
                       "app_name" => "[REDACTED]",
    "iphone_app_emulated_on_ipad" => false,
                          "4inch" => true,
                            "git" => {
        "remote_origin" => "git@github.com:jmoody/calabash-ios-server.git",
               "branch" => "master",
             "revision" => "adde106"
    },
                    "app_version" => "2.0.1",
                    "iOS_version" => "7.1",
                         "system" => "x86_64",
                      "simulator" => "iPhone Simulator 463.9.41, iPhone OS 7.1 (iPhone Retina (4-inch)/11D167)"
}
```

Comment: Please add the error console log...
You may need to set APP_BUNDLE_PATH

Comment: I do set the `APP_BUNDLE_PATH` like so: `APP_BUNDLE_PATH = "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[Project Name]-ecqxvrsnmjuqujfwxaoiruzmutmx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/[App Name]"`. I am not getting any error messages in the console but I am getting a popup that says path not found. However the path definitely exists.

Comment: Open simulator, do you see that your app-cal target is installed in the simulator. If the app is installed in the simulator, keep it background and open a terminal type `calabash-ios` console to open a ruby console and in there type `start_test_server_in_background` and check the simulator launching with app-cal app. Tell us what is the result.

Comment: Yes, the target is installed in the simulator. However, when I go into the calabash console and run `start_test_server_in_background`, I get the following errors: `RuntimeError: Error... Unable to find APP_BUNDLE_PATH.
Cannot find a built app that is linked with calabash.framework
Please build your app from Xcode
You should build your calabash target.

Alternatively, specify APP_BUNDLE_PATH in features/support/01_launch.rb
This should point to the location of your built app linked with calabash.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok,that means calabash cannot locate the your app.

Try this first,

1. Comment out the APP_BUNDLE_PATH definition on 
   YourProject/features/support/01_launch.rb like `#APP_BUNDLE_PATH =
   "~/..../../myApp-cal.app"`  so The calabash gem can locate the app
   automatically.
2. Open a console go to the project folder from it. Then enter `gem install calabash-cucumber` this will install the calabash gem its ok to run again even if you installed it previously there's no harm. Then enter `calabash-ios setup` in that terminal, this will create  a calabash target and add the calabash framework to your iOS project. more details about the setup process is mentioned in [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios).
3. Now open the project file in xcode editor (You can see the calabash.framework added to your project's framework group successfully.) select the yourApp-cal target and the simulator you want clean, build and run the yourApp-cal target on your simulator.
4. Then stop it and come back to that console enter `calabash-ios console` console will start a ruby console that you can work with the app. now (while simulator is on your screen but your app is backbround on that simulator) type `start_test_server_in_background` your app must come to foreground. If that works the calabash can find and run your app on simulator.
5. Remember only if you create an app build on a separate folder using a xcodebuild command or script or something, thats the time to set the APP_BUNDLE_PATH variable.

Comment: More about calabash customizing check here https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/01-Getting-started-guide

Comment: Thanks--this fixed it. Previously I was trying to use Cocoapods to install, and I think that's at least part of the reason I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Chathura's answer worked for one of my colleagues, but a couple of us had to find another solution.

The issue for us occurred after introducing CocoaPods. In Xcode, I opened Organizer and noticed we had a derived data folder for the BP (before Pods) project and another for the workspace with Pods. I deleted the derived data folder for the BP project and then everything worked.

I had re-setup calabash before doing this, so the solution in my case may have been a combination of Chathura's answer and mine.